# Retain backslashes with while read loop in multiple shells

Tags: while-loop, escaping, sh, portability, backslash

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line; do
        printf "%s\n" $line
done < input.txt
```

Input.txt has the following lines:

```
one\two
eight\nine
```

The output is as follows

```
onetwo
eightnine
```

The "standard" solutions to retain the slashes would be to use `read -r`.
However, I have the following limitations:

- must run under `#!/bin/sh`for reasons of portability/posix compliance.
- not all systems
  will support the `-r` switch to read under /sh
- The input file format cannot be changed

Therefore, I am looking for another way to retain the backslash after reading in the line.  I have come up with one working solution, which is to use `sed` to replace the `\` with some other value (e.g.`||`) into a temporary file (thus bypassing my last requirement above) then, after reading them in use `sed` again to transform it back.  Like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -e 's/[\/&]/||/g' input.txt > tempfile.txt
while read line; do
        printf "%s\n" $line | sed -e 's/||/\\/g'
done < tempfile.txt
```

I'm thinking there has to be a more "graceful" way of doing this.
Some ideas:
1) Use command substitution to store this into a variable instead of a file.  Problem - I'm not sure command substitution will be portable here either and my attempts at using a variable instead of a file were unsuccessful.  Regardless, file or variable the base solution is really the same (two substitutions).

2) Use IFS somehow?  I've investigated a little, but not sure that can help in this issue.

3) ???

What are some better ways to handle this given my constraints?

Thanks

Comment: Your first two constraints are contradictory. `read -r` is specified by POSIX, so if you have machines that don't accept `read -r`, then they aren't POSIX-compliant.

Comment: Tell that to Solaris :).  The script is written in `#!/bin/sh` to run in lowest common denominator.  Unfortunately, though bash on Solaris supports `read -r`, the /sh script there does not.  There is a `/usr/bin/read` that supports it, but that can't be call in a while loop.  So I don't think my constraints are contradictory as much as Solaris is broken.  But, when all else is said and done I want solutions that will work on all platforms under /sh.

Comment: On that note though.  How does one definitively state that the `-r` switch is POSIX compliance?  Meaning, where does one look as reference to see if something is supported by POSIX?  So, if I say to someone "run this on a POSIX compliant shell" and they tell me `read -r` doesn't work, I can then say well your shell isn't POSIX compliant then if it doesn't support this option?

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ and specifically http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html

Comment: `/bin/sh` is not POSIX-complian under Solaris, but I believe they do ship a POSIX-compliant shell in a different directory (from what I've seen posted in other questions).

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints seem a little strict. Here's a piece of code I jotted down(I'm not too sure of how valuable your `while` loop is for the other stuffs you would like to do, so I removed it off just for ease). I don't guarantee this code to be robustness. But anyway, the logic would give you hints in the direction you may wish to proceed. (`temp.dat` is the input file)

```
#!/bin/sh
var1="$(cut -d\\ -f1 temp.dat)"
var2="$(cut -d\\ -f2 temp.dat)"

iter=1

set -- $var2
for x in $var1;do
    if [ "$iter" -eq 1 ];then
        echo $x "\\"  $1
    else
        echo $x "\\" $2
    fi
    iter=$((iter+1))
done
```

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to be another solution and technically more "graceful" as w aren't modifying the data at any point.  I will have to read up more on your use of `set --` here as I'm not sure how it works.  While this solution provides one possible answer to the data I provided, I should have been more clear in that I want to be able to parse the input data regardless of any backslashes or other special characters.  So, even if the line were `blah/booo boo/blahbla/ boo / / / blah` it would read that line in as is.  Your parsing solution could possibly be dynamic?

Comment: It's simple for another delimiter. Just have a `shell variable` that has the necessary delimiter and replace that variable with every instance of `\\\` in the code above. Let me know if you face any difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

As Larry Wall once said, writing a portable shell is easier than writing a portable shell script.

```
perl -lne 'print $_' input.txt
```

The simplest possible Perl script is simpler still, but I imagine you'll want to do something with `$_` before printing it.

Comment: As mentioned in the OP and Jerry states - my constraints are script, but those are the guidelines I'm working within.  Think of it as a creative exercise even if you don't agree on the constraints.  I am delivering this script to a wide array of UNIX and Linux systems and we can't be guaranteed they have bash or perl.  I don't necessarily have control of what gets put on there.